# Forward a file download in sinatra using streaming

Tags: ruby, stream, streaming, sinatra, rack

I have made a ruby / sinatra website and I need to let the user to download a file.
 This file is not local hosted, it is hosted on a remote API. end user must not see the true origin of the file.

```
get "/files/:elementKey/masterfile" do
  content_type "application/octet-stream"  
  loadMasterfile(params[:elementKey])
end
```

With loadMasterfile:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(plainURI,443)
 http.use_ssl = true; 
 http.start do |http|
   req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(resource, {"User-Agent" =>"API downloader"})
   req.basic_auth(user.keytechUserName, user.keytechPassword)
   response = http.request(req)     
   # return this as a file attachment
   attachment( response["X-Filename"])  #Use the sinatra helper to set this as filename
   response.body  << This lets sinatra download the file and then forward the whole content to the browser  
 end
```

This code works, but: 
 The file is downloaded first to the ruby/sinatra and then forwarded to the browser. 
 User must wait until download starts - browser seems to freeze.

Is there a solution to start a download form a remote API and forward the contents in one flow?

I found nothing about that or just found solutions for local file downloads, but I must download a file from a remote API.

I also can not cache the file locally or on Amazon AWS.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try with a gem such as HTTPClient? You can apparently use it in a streaming fashion like explained [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.3.4.1/HTTPClient/Connection), see example 2 (if I understand correctly what they are doing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this in a streaming fashion in which your app is the proxy, you'll need to send the client chunks *as you are downloading chunks*. This is not the default behavior of ruby / `Net::HTTP`, but it is possible.

From the ruby docs:

> By default Net::HTTP reads an entire response into memory. If you are handling large files or wish to implement a progress bar you can instead stream the body directly to an IO.

Streaming is possible through `read_body`, though.

[`Net::HTTP` Streaming Response Bodies](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Streaming+Response+Bodies)

Example usage from the docs:

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/large_file')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

  http.request request do |response|
    open 'large_file', 'w' do |io|
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        io.write chunk
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This example from the docs writes the streaming data to a file, but you could replace it with writes to your response stream. In combination with [Sinatra's streaming api](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Streaming%20Responses), the code might look like this:

```
get "/files/:elementKey/masterfile" do
  content_type "application/octet-stream"

  stream do |out|
    loadMasterfile(params[:elementKey]) do |chunk|
      out << chunk
    end
  end
end


def loadMasterfile(resource, &block)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(plainURI, 443)
  http.use_ssl = true; 
  http.start do |http|
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(resource, {"User-Agent" =>"API downloader"})
    req.basic_auth(user.keytechUserName, user.keytechPassword)
    http.request(req) do |origin_repsonse|
      origin_repsonse.read_body(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how you'd set the filename. You'd also want to handle errors appropriately in the net calls and stream close. Also note that a front-end like nginx can affect the buffering / chunking of streaming responses.

Comment: Tanks for the late answer. Still very valuable.